# How can this HTML page have multiple <html> tags and still work?

Tags: html

I notice that some Stackoverflow questions say that having multiple `<html>` tags on a single html page results in an invalid document ([example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035462/multiple-htmlbody-html-body-in-same-file), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786987/multiple-html-tags-in-html-file-how-to-separate-css-rules-when-classes-and-id))

However, I came across [this page](http://www.cpppc.org:8082/efmisweb/ppp/projectLibrary/getProjInfoNational.do?projId=0008aa9b6bb04b9180d4d9a597b020b4) which used multiple `<html>` and `</html>` tags but still displays properly. Is it because HTML has changed? Or is it because each `<html>` tag is used to display a specific tab on each page?

Comment: Afaik, a page can only have one HTML tag. The browser might be letting it slide for the sake of making it work. Some browsers are really lenient about what invalid markup is rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that this (i.e. the page you linked to) is simply invalid (i.e. wrong) code. If you open the browser tools in that page, you see that the browser not only ignores all those superfluous HTML tags, but even filters them out - you won't find them in the code (inside the Inspector). So the browser automatically corrects these errors and the page is displayed more or less correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is the browser being tolerant of faulty html. The html is invalid, however the browser is able to correct this itself and successfully render the page. Since the 2nd  appears after the `<head>`, the browser is probably able to correctly deduce that this is incorrect and ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

The only time a source code can have multiple html tags is when there are `iframe` tags or older `frame` tags. Iframes for example can have a whole html page inside them